# how can I control the font-size in html2canvas

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm using [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) that creates pdf from html code. It uses [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). The result is very good but slightly different from the original: the font-size and line-height are a little bit different so that the end of the page is not correct. I really need a copy if the div (that has fixed aspect to be correctly rendered on A4 pages).

Is there a way to influence the fonts in the final rendering? The way I produce pdf now is:

```
   savePdf () {
      this.pdfDialog = true
      let opt = {
        // if set firefox will not be able to print as pdf!...
        // margin: 0,
        filename: 'cv.pdf',
        enableLinks: true,
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: {
          scale: 8,
          useCORS: true,
          width: 310,
          letterRendering: true,
        },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
      }
      html2pdf().set(opt).from(document.getElementById('printable-cv')).save()]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add inline styles to the elements. In my case, working in vuejs I ended up with this code:

```
<div class="presentazione" v-html="presentation" :style="presentationFont"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Tailwind and encountered a similar problem. Found this solution:

Since html2canvas append div tag to body to get some metrics, we can do the following:

```
@layer base {
  img {
    @apply inline-block;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2775